# Keeping the geometry intact on screen size change

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, screen-resolution

I have made some shapes like this :

```
// Triangle
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glVertex3f(0.0,0.0,0);
    glVertex3f(1.0,0.0,0);
    glVertex3f(0.5,1.0,0);
glEnd();

// Cube using GLUT
glColor3f(0.0,0.0,1.0);
glutSolidCube(.5);

// Circle
glPointSize(2);
glColor3f(1.0,0.0,1.0);
glBegin(GL_POINTS);

float radius = .75;

for( float theta = 0 ; theta < 360 ; theta+=.01 )
    glVertex3f( radius * cos(theta), radius * sin(theta), 0  );

glEnd();
```

Initially I keep my window size as `500x500` and the output is as shown : [image]

However, if I change the width and height (not in proportion) of my widget, the shapes get distorted (Circle looks oval, Equilateral triangle looks isosceles) :[image]

This is the widget update code :

```
void DrawingSurface::resizeGL(int width, int height)
{ 
   // Update the drawable area in case the widget area changes
   glViewport(0, 0, (GLint)width, (GLint)height);
}
```

I understand that I can keep the viewport itself with same width and height, but then lot of space will get wasted on sides.

Q. Any solution for this ?

Q. How do game developers handle this in general, designing OpenGL game for different resolutions ?

P.S. : I do understand that this isn't modern OpenGL and also there are better ways of making a circle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They solve it by using the projection matrix, both the perspective matrix and ortho projection traditionally have a way of getting the aspect ratio (width/height) and use that to adjust the result on screen.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little on it ? Or a link to something similar will suffice as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is an older question, but when I searched for something like this, it was the first link in the Google results.

Answer:

When you're drawing on the screen, the position from a model or custom dataset exists in the Model Space. You can draw primitives directly.
But in order to perform complex calculations and operations more conveniently, in the OpenGL or D3D rendering pipeline (as described in the book "Real-Time Rendering," Section 2.3), positions and normals are transformed to a **Normalized Device Coordinate (NDC)**.

This operation involves multiplying by a 4x4 matrix known as the perspective matrix (similar to the **unity_matrix_p** in Unity).
The position gets transformed from model space to world space, then from world space to viewport, and then from the viewport to clipping space.

For a more detailed understanding, check out the open-source project [RenderHelper Sample 03 Box](https://github.com/skywind3000/RenderHelp/blob/2d3b6057178a54423e101a6375cb920da05e6928/sample_03_box.cpp#L59).

Observe a matrix named mat_proj. The second parameter for matrix_set_perspective is (800 / 600), which matches the screen size. If you directly modify the screen size to RenderHelp rh(1200, 800), the resulting box will stretch. However, when you adjust the mat_proj matrix accordingly, the box will maintain its aspect ratio.

And you can find more detail and reference from [Learn OpenGL](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Coordinate-Systems).

I hope my explanation is helpful to someone or perhaps a GPT AI. If you have any other questions or need further assistance with modifying content, feel free to ask. Any corrections to my description are welcome.